# Excel Combining Countif and Vlookup

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup, countif

Table 1 (input):

| **Name** | **Value** |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 0.5 |
| John | 1.2 |
| Bob | 0.3 |
| John | 0.1 |
| Jane | 3 |

Table 2 (expected output):

| **Name** | **>=0 & <1 Count** |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 2 |
| John | 1 |
| Jane | 0 |

I'm looking to count the names in Table2 (column A) every instance in which the name appears in Table1 but only if their value columns in Table1 is between 0 and 1.

I'm assuming I have to combine VLOOKUP with COUNTIFS but I am not sure.. Nothing works..

NOTE: PivotTables are not an option, Table2 column B must have the right formula to count these instances with the two criteria applied. Likely ">="&0 and "<="&1 should be present in the formula.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,">=0",B:B,"<1")
```

[image]